# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first when create custom view class

Tags: java, android

When create Custom View Class and run, logcat console shows error.

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4312)

How can fix I it?

Here is my code:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    ArrayList<Item> alTemp;
    ArrayList<Item> alViews;
    Bitmap bitmap2;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int frontBack;
    Context mContext;
    Templates mTemplates;
    RelativeLayout root;
    float scale;

    public CanvasView(Context context, float scale, ArrayList<Item> arrayList, Templates templates, int frontBack, Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap bitmap2) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.alTemp = arrayList;
        this.mTemplates = templates;
        this.frontBack = frontBack;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.bitmap2 = bitmap2;
        setData();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        root.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        root.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        root.draw(canvas);
        root.setLayerType(1, null);
    }


    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        root.measure(w, h);
        root.layout(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    public void setData() {
        alViews = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < alTemp.size(); i++) {
            if (frontBack == alTemp.get(i).getFrontback()) {
                alViews.add(alTemp.get(i));
            }
        }
        root = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        root.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveHeight));
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveHeight));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        if (frontBack == 0) {
            if (mTemplates.getFrontTemplatetype() == 2) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(Functions.setFrontTemplate(mContext, mTemplates, Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveHeight));
            }
        } else if (mTemplates.getBackTemplatetype() == 2) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(Functions.setBackTemplate(mContext, mTemplates, Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveHeight));
        }
        root.addView(imageView);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveWidth));
        root.addView(relativeLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < alViews.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("loop " + i);
            RelativeLayout relLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            relLayout.setX((float) Math.round(alViews.get(i).getRlx() * scale));
            relLayout.setY((float) Math.round(alViews.get(i).getRly() * scale));
            relLayout.setRotation(alViews.get(i).getRlrotation());
            relLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            if (alViews.get(i).getType() == 0) {
                CustomTextView customTextView = new CustomTextView(mContext);
                String stringBuilder = " " +
                        alViews.get(i).getText().trim() +
                        " ";
                customTextView.setText(stringBuilder);
                customTextView.setTextColor((alViews.get(i)).getTextcolor());
                customTextView.setTextSize(0, (float) Math.round(((float) alViews.get(i).getTextsize()) * scale));
                customTextView.setGravity(alViews.get(i).getGravity());
                customTextView.setTypeface(alViews.get(i).getTextstyle());
                customTextView.setAlpha(((float) alViews.get(i).getOpacity()) / 100.0f);
                if (alViews.get(i).isTextunderline()) {
                    customTextView.setPaintFlags(customTextView.getPaintFlags() | 8);
                } else {
                    customTextView.setPaintFlags(customTextView.getPaintFlags() & -9);
                }
                if (alViews.get(i).isStroke()) {
                    customTextView.setStroke(true);
                    customTextView.setStrokeColor(alViews.get(i).getStrokeColor());
                    customTextView.setStrokeWidth(Math.round(((float) alViews.get(i).getStrokeWidth()) * scale));
                    customTextView.invalidate();
                }
                if (alViews.get(i).isShadow()) {
                    customTextView.setShadow(true);
                    customTextView.setShadowWidth(Math.round(alViews.get(i).getShadowSize() * scale));
                    customTextView.setShadowX(Math.round(alViews.get(i).getShadowX() * scale));
                    customTextView.setShadowY(Math.round(alViews.get(i).getShadowY() * scale));
                    customTextView.setShadowColor(alViews.get(i).getShadowColor());
                    customTextView.invalidate();
                }
                customTextView.setPadding(0, 0, (int) customTextView.getShadowX(), (int) customTextView.getShadowY());
                customTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                relativeLayout.setClipToPadding(true);
                relativeLayout.addView(customTextView);
            } else if (alViews.get(i).getType() == 1 ||alViews.get(i).getType()==2) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(alViews.get(i).getImagebitmap());
                imageView.setAlpha(((float) alViews.get(i).getOpacity()) / 100.0f);
                if (alViews.get(i).getColorFilter() != -1) {
                    imageView.setColorFilter((alViews.get(i)).getColorFilter());
                }
                LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LayoutParams(Math.round((((float) alViews.get(i).getIvSize()) * scale) * alViews.get(i).getScaleW()), Math.round((((float) alViews.get(i).getIvSize()) * scale) * alViews.get(i).getScaleH()));
                layoutParams2.setMargins(Math.round(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_margin) * scale), Math.round(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_margin) * scale), Math.round(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_margin) * scale), Math.round(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_margin) * scale));
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
            }
            root.addView(relativeLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you're using the  `relativeLayout` variable within your loop rather than `relLayout`

Which means that `relativeLayout` is added to it's parent once for each loop iteration plus before the loop.

I believe you need

```
    ...
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Constants.saveWidth, Constants.saveWidth));
    root.addView(relativeLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < alViews.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("loop " + i);
        RelativeLayout relLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relLayout.setX((float) Math.round(alViews.get(i).getRlx() * scale));
        relLayout.setY((float) Math.round(alViews.get(i).getRly() * scale));
        relLayout.setRotation(alViews.get(i).getRlrotation());
        relLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        if (alViews.get(i).getType() == 0) {
            ...
            relLayout.setClipToPadding(true);
            relLayout.addView(customTextView);
        } 
        ...
        root.addView(relLayout);

    }
}
```

However, from looking at your code it looks as though it might be easier for you to define your layout as an XML file and load it into your view.

It looks as though you're rendering views for each item in the `allTemp` array. This really looks like a good use of a recycler view which I believe would serve you much better.

This might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: thanks but i wanna custom view to be added dynamically data

Comment: Did the first part fix your problem? And you can still do that. You could have a custom view that you pass data to, and that custom view could hold a recycler view. It would save you having to manually add each view. If you have a lot of data that can have performance implications.